# Java cast Object to MyClass

Tags: java, generics, casting, jackson

I'm writing a storage manager. I want to read from file to object. Example:

```
protected Object read(String key) throws Exception{
    Path pathReadFrom = Paths.get(getPath(key));

    if (!Files.isReadable(pathReadFrom)){
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    Object object = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(Files.readAllBytes(pathReadFrom), Object.class);
    return object;
}
```

JSON_MAPPER is Jackson's ObjectMapper.

```
public MyClass get(String id) throws Exception {
    MyClass myClassObject = (MyClass) storeManager.read(id);
    return myClassObject;
}
```

I get the next exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.pckg.project.dto.MyClass
```

How can I create universal **read()** method? Maybe should I set a type like  second argument of read() method?

Comment: What is your reason for creating this storage manager?

Comment: you're not actually explaining how your code is writing the object to the file. if the way you write is not consistent with the way you read (and from the exception seem so) it will never work.
Please add the code of the write() method

Comment: I write a web app without DB, so I store data in json format on hdd. That's why I need a storeManager.

Comment: Also--is this Jackson 1? Modern versions of `ObjectMapper` don't have a `read` method.

Comment: I write object to the file. And I get this object in read method. It works, just believe me. The question is how to create universal method for reading from json file to object and then cast it to whatever

Comment: It clearly *doesn't* work because you're the objects as unstructured maps instead of the intended type. Using Jackson 2 with the appropriate generic `readValue` methods would probably solve the (immediate) problem.

Comment: As you can see Jackson reads the JSON content into a `LinkedHashMap` to have ordered key-value-pairs. How should that be casted into a type which has absolutely no relation with a `LinkedHashMap`? If you want a "universal reader" (which sounds like reinventing stuff, that Jackson already can do), then create a method which can take the items from the map to initialize its fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought up some solution:

```
protected <T> T read(String key, Class<T> valueType) throws Exception{
    Path pathReadFrom = Paths.get(getPath(key));
    T object = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(Files.readAllBytes(pathReadFrom), valueType);
    return object;
}

public MyClass get(String id) throws Exception {
    MyClass object = storeManager.read(id, MyClass.class);
    return object;
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: The `isReadable()` test is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to specify proper target type to use: otherwise Jackson has no idea of what kind of class you might want to get -- you are just telling it to "create a `java.lang.Object` out of JSON", which it happily does by using so-called "untyped" mode: JSON Objects become `java.util.Map`s, JSON Arrays `java.util.List`s, JSON Strings regular Java Strings and so on.

So if you want to get JSON bound to Class `MyClass`, you will pass `MyClass.class` instead of `Object.class`.

Answer (score -1):

How can you cast unrelated objects? In what way are LinkedHashMap and MyClass are related? You need to map them manually (or may be with help of something equivalent of AutoMapper for .NET)

Comment: I don't want to returns LinkedHashMap :) I want somehow to send the type convert to.

Comment: I see. May be : MyClass object = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(Files.readAllBytes(pathReadFrom), MyClass.class);

Comment: Man :) It is too easy. I need the method which returns me any classes. It has to look like - read(String key, AnyClass class); JSON_MAPPER.readValue(Files.readAllBytes(pathReadFrom), class);